# Determining if $[0,0,1]$ is a linear combination of the giving vector or not.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I am giving the vectors $\{[1,1,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,1]\}$ and am supposed to determine whether $[0,0,1]$ is a linear combination of the given vectors or not.

I tried solving the problem several times and keep getting the wrong answer. Yet also I'am not completely sure if I'm setting up the augmented matrices right or not.

Comment: First vector minus Half the 2nd vector.

Comment: I know that is the answer, yet I need to show my work by matrices.

Comment: I'm just now sure how to set it up, because when I do I keep getting the wrong answer for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $[2,2,2]=\frac 23[1,1,2]+\frac 23[2,2,1]$, we only need to consider if $[0,0,1]$ can be expressed as a linear combination of $[1,1,2]$ and $[2,2,1]$. This is equivalent to asking if $\{[1,1,2],[2,2,1],[0,0,1]\}$ forms a linearly independent set, the problem can be solve of finding the determinant of
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$$
. It turns out that $\det A=0$, so each row vectors are linearly dependent, hence $[0,0,1]$ can be written as a linear combination of another 2 vectors. By substituting the last row by any other row vector, you can determining if $[a,b,c]$ can be written as linear combination of $\{[1,1,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,1]\}$ by finding if 
$$
\det \left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 1 \\
a & b & c
\end{matrix}\right)$$
is equal to $0$ or not.